# VCC and GND islands on TOP layer

Tags: pcb-design, layout, pcb-layers, ground-plane

I was checking Intel Tiger Lake UP3 reference board layout and I noticed that they made core VCC islands on top layer and through vias they connected to a layer that has the bigger/continuous plane of the same VCC. same thing for ground, they made an island on top, and had several GND layers that are all GND.

Is this better than connecting the BGA on top layer directly through via to the plane at the middle of the board? any why?

Note: the CPU is placed on PCB Top layer.
[image]

Comment: The primary concern for bga solder process with ground planes  is that having different types of bga connections with different thermal properties can be challenging for the assembler,  sinking a bga via directly to a large board sized internal plane can make solder risky ( the plane is a big heatsink ). This example  could be an attempt at a compromise or to equalize thermal properties for better yield,  or it could be for another design reason like wanting to save on vias to allow for more clearance for internal  breakout. Or it could be for yet another reason like power dissipation.